# Laptop without display port and monitor 4K

Tags: usb, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a Dell Inspiron 5548 laptop with USB 2 and 3 and no Displayport and no USB C.

I can use my new Samsung LU28E590DS LED 4K monitor with 30HZ on Windows and Linux but I can't get it working with 60HZ and the highest resolution. Unfortunately it's laggy with 30HZ...

I think it's related to cables/ports. A friend of mine has the same monitor and USB C and it does work for him by using an adapter/conversor (Displayport > USB C). Unfortunately this is not an option for me.

How can I get it working with the highest resolution and 60HZ on both Linux and Windows?

Comment: Please indicate how your Dell is connecting to the monitor.  I assume HDMI?  Be specific about the makes/brands of the cables and adapters, because USB 3.1 Gen 2 is not transmitted across all cables.

Comment: If you're using HDMI, the laptop needs to support HDMI 2.0 to do 4K@60hz. It doesn't look like either of the GPUs in that laptop support HDMI 2.0.

Comment: It appears you accidentally created two accounts. [Check the help center](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) for information on how to fix this. // It is entirely possible there is no solution. Do you need 3D acceleration or anything the like?